# Dynamic card with condition using Angular & Bootstrap

Tags: angular, dynamic, bootstrap-cards

I'm trying to make my cards dynamic but they have a condition. I checked the angular doc and I couldn't find the answer. Basically I have a cards component with the condition of clicking on a nav link it shows one set of cards and the other shows another set of cards. The component cards calls the card-item 3 times for each condition. In my component card item I can't seem to find how to apply that condition and refer to either set of card-item content in my ts. Here's the code.

```
<--! HTML OF CARDS -->

 <div class="cardbg">
     <ul class="nav topnav active justify-content-center">
      <li class="nav-item item-1">
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="toggle(1)">Je suis Consultant</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item item-2">
        <a class="nav-link" (click)="toggle(2)">Je suis Partenaire</a>
      </li>
    </ul>


  <hr class="m-0">


     <!-- OFFRES -->
    <div *ngIf="consulant">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
        <h4 class="mt-3">Offres</h4>
      </div>
      <app-card-item>[offres]="offres"</app-card-item>
      <app-card-item>[offres]="offres"</app-card-item>
      <app-card-item>[offres]="offres"</app-card-item>
    </div>

    <!--  CV  -->
    <div *ngIf="company">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
          <h4 class="mt-3">CV</h4>
        </div>
        <app-card-item>[cv]="cv"</app-card-item>
        <app-card-item>[cv]="cv"</app-card-item>
        <app-card-item>[cv]="cv"</app-card-item>
    </div>


</div>

<--! TS OF CARDS -->
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-cards",
  templateUrl: "./cards.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./cards.component.scss"]
})
export class CardsComponent implements OnInit {



 constructor() { }

   company: boolean = false;
   consulant: boolean = true;

   toggle(elem: number) {
     if (elem == 1) {
     this.consulant = true;
     this.company = false;
   }
   if (elem == 2) {
    this.consulant = false;
   this.company = true;
   }
 }
 ngOnInit() {}
 }

<--! HTML OF CARD ITEM -->

<div class="row mx-2">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-4" *ngFor="let x of card-item">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{x.titre}}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{x.contenu}}</p>
          <p class="card-subtitle">{{x.montant}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>

 <-- TS OF CARD-ITEM -->

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-card-item',
   templateUrl: './card-item.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./card-item.component.scss']
   })
  export class CardItemComponent implements OnInit {


    offres = [
    {titre: "Architectes Sécurité",
    contenu: "Nous recherchons un Architecte sécurité pour une mission longue (3 mois 
    renouvelables horizon 2 ans voire plus) Paris intra-muros.",
    montant: " Partenaire historique F2I - TJM 700€"
    },
   {titre: "ingénieur de Production AIX/LINUX",
   contenu: "Nous recherchons un Ingénieur de Production AIX/LINUX sur St Quentin (78) pour 
   une mission de plusieurs mois.",
   montant: "Partenaire historique F2I - TJM 600€"
   },
  {titre: "Chef de Projet Technique",
  contenu: "Nous rechercons un Concepteur Technique / Chef de projet Contexte : Fusion de 
  deux plateformes et d'une migration d'une soixantaine de sites Missions.",
  montant: "Partenaire historique F2I - TJM 600€"
  }

 ]

 cv = [
 {titre: "Expert JAVA SWING / JEE / JAVA",
  contenu: "Ingénieur d'étude (30 ans - 78 Versailles). AB INITO, C++? COBRA, ORACLE, POWER 
 AMC, SCRIPT SHELL, DATASTAGE, DECISIONNEL, Big Data.",
 montant: "TJM: 500€"
 },
 {titre: "Architecte UNIX",
 contenu: "Architecte, Consultant Technique - Architecte (35 ans - 77 Villeparisis). UNIX, 
 VMWARE, CITRIX, WINDOWS.",
 montant: "TJM: 650€"

 },
 {titre: "PROJECT MANAGEMENT OFFICE",
 contenu: "Assistant à Maîtrise d'Ouvrage - PMO (32 ans - 75 Paris). PROJECT MANAGEMENT 
 OFFICE, MS OFFICE, MS PROJECT? GLOBAL PORTFOLIO.",
 montant: "TJM: 500€"

   }
 ]

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
 }

}
```

Comment: Hi, first of all you should learn about @Input() declaration, as u try to use cv and offres as input, while u r not declaring it as such. Also I would extract the offres and cv arrays and put it in the parent component, which is passing the data as inputs like u declared it in ur html [cv]="cv". If u expect these values to change use ngOnChanges on the cardItemComponent. Also cuzrrently u try to pass offres and cv as input to the cardItemComponent without declaring them on ur ts file. My guess is they are undefined. Ur toggle function with setting true and false seems to be right. regards+#

Comment: Hello Sagat. Thxs for your help. The issue is that I need the card-items to be called in another page without the rest of what's in the cards component that includes a navbar that has a toggle condition of displaying one of the other set of cards. The array you speak of needs to be removed, it's something I started but didn't work. If I understand correctly it's not possible to have a condition in card-items component linked to a condition in cards component?